# A decorator that works on every function

Tags: python, python-decorators

I want to print Hello World on every function call and I'm using decorators to achieve this.

```
def hello_decorator(fn):
    def ret_fn(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Hello world")
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return ret_fn
```

Assuming that this caused a function to error out, while an undecorated version of that function worked fine, what might be the problem with the decorator?  The issue isn't with print since I can remove that and the issue remains.

Is there a better way to wrap a function and call it exactly the way it would have been called without the prototype?

Comment: This is not a valid decorator. A decorator should return a function.

Comment: Take a look at [wrapt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wrapt).

Comment: What do you mean by “called without the prototype”. Can you explain further?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE read as called, without knowing the prototype.  I meant how can you decorate an arbitrary function without knowing it's prototype?

Comment: @1419636215 Exactly as you currently do, by passing `*args` and `**kwargs` straight through. Further, you can use [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to preserve more details of the decorated function (e.g. name, docstring, etc.)

Comment: @Josh what about functions which accept dictionaries as arguments, won't they be confused with the **kwargs?

Comment: Nope, since `kwargs` is a dictionary on its own (that may contain other dictionaries if the function was called with a dictionary). e.g. if you have a function defined as `foo(*args, **kwargs)` and call it with `foo(1, 2, [0.5, 0.6], blah={3: 4, 5: 6})`, then `args` will be `[1, 2, [0.5, 0.6]]` and `kwargs` will be `{"blah": {3: 4, 5: 6}}`.

Comment: Ah.  That clears it up.  it seems my code *should* be working but isn't for some reason.
I'm trying to use a logging dict configurator, but I get the error `Unable to configure filter 'require_debug_false': __import__() argument 1 must be string, not DictConfigurator` when I use the above decorator on __import__

Answer (score 0):

A decorator must return a function.

```
def hello_decorator(fn):
    def ret_fn(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Hello world")
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return ret_fn
```

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've edited the code in the question.